# not able to run sudo apt-get command on my ubuntu machine

Tags: 16.04

After doing some research I narrowed down to that there is some issue with my source.list file.

I am attaching the error and my source.list file. Can someone guide me which lines should I remove/update/insert to make it work.

I have already commented few lines that reduced the number of error I was getting. Now, I am not able to proceed further.

Error

```
W:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' 
does not have a Release file.

W:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file.,

W:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release' does not have a Release file., 

W:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file.

E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/multiverse/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80], 

E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80], 

E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80], 

E:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/multiverse/source/Sources  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80],
```

Source.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse universe 
restricted main #Added by software-properties
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse universe restricted main #Added by software-properties
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted 
universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse universe restricted main #Added by software-properties
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Comment: "Connection failed" looks like a temporary connection issue. You can restore sources.list using Software and Updates app and selecting the updates you want to receive.

Comment: maybe you're behind some company/university proxy that for whatever reason blocks access to archive.ubuntu.com ?

Comment: I am able to access archive.ubuntu.com If I try directly through browser.  I am not even able to install anything using apt-get @Rovo

Comment: Yes, thanks @Rovo. I tried with different wifi and it worked, my company's wifi must be blocking some IPs